# how to count specific keys in an array with objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that looks like this :

```
[ 

  { id: 9,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 10,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 11,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 12,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 13,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'joystick',
    date: 2019-03-11 },

    etc...............


]
```

**NOTE** keys of objects in array are static, but values are dynamic except for email => the email is static

**NOTE2** the length of array are dynamic not static, so the number of objects are dynamic

how to filter this array to get the result like this

```
{
    email: 'user@example.com', // email here is static AKA is known
    handbag: 4, // keys here , not just keys they are the values of keys in objects in array , and i want to use them like has access to them
    smartphone: 1,
    joystick: 1,

    etc.......
}
```

So the final line of out put to the client to be something like this:

> You have 4 products of handbag and 1 product of joystick and 1 product of smartphone etc.................

**NOTE** I don't know the length of the last object , and i don't know the length of array, all data are dynamic except for email.

This question, I think it's a little bit of challenge.

Comment: what is the key? you got a static email, why not use it as hash?

Comment: @NinaScholz i get this data from db, so i filtered where email, now i use this email to get data from products table. the product table has the above array and objects for this specific user. and i want to put all available data to his front end in one line of code so mapping and loop function won't work

Comment: please add the wanted result of the above data. and the code, you tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz updated the question with the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce like this:

```js
const data = [{ id: 9,email: 'user@example.com',product: 'handbag',date: 2019-03-11 },{ id: 10,email: 'user@example.com',product: 'handbag',date: 2019-03-11 },{ id: 11,email: 'user@example.com',product: 'handbag',date: 2019-03-11 },{ id: 12,email: 'user@example.com',product: 'handbag',date: 2019-03-11 },{ id: 13,email: 'user@example.com',product: 'joystick',date: 2019-03-11 }];
const result = data.reduce((acc, {product}) => (acc[product] = (acc[product]||0)+1, acc),
                           { email: data[0].email });
console.log(result);

const phrase = `${result.email} you have in your account ${
    Object.entries(result).map(([k, v]) => k!=="email" && `${v} ${k}${v>1?"s":""}`)
          .filter(Boolean).join(" and ")
}`;
console.log(phrase);
```

The first part of the code uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) so that the so-called accumulator is returned after the assignment to `acc[product]` is made.

The `||0` is needed when `acc[product]` does not yet exist, and then the counting must start from 0.

`{ email: data[0].email }` is the initial value of the accumulator that `reduce` builds on. It is the start of the object that will be extended with the other properties.

Comment: great now i want to put this dynamic obj in one line of output as result to appear to client

Comment: great thank you this help me , and solved my issue , i just wanted to ask you do you have any reference so i can read to understand more about  this line of code 

`data.reduce((acc, {product}) => (acc[product] = (acc[product]||0)+1, acc), { email: data[0].email });`

Comment: Added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use reduce to reduce the array down to an object.

```js
const items = [ 

  { id: 9,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 10,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 11,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 12,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'handbag',
    date: 2019-03-11 },
  { id: 13,
    email: 'user@example.com',
    product: 'joystick',
    date: 2019-03-11 }
]

let result = items.reduce((obj, itm) => {
  obj.email = itm.email
  obj[itm.product] = obj[itm.product] + 1 || 1
  return obj
}, {})

let str = []

Object.entries(result).forEach(entry => {
  if(entry[0] == 'email') return
  str.push(`${entry[1]} products of ${entry[0]}`)
})

document.body.innerHTML = `You have ${str.join(' and ')}`
```

Comment: great now i want to put this dynamic obj in one line of output as result to appear to client

Comment: I have updated the answer to display the results on the page